# How to differentiate these type of problems?

Tags: calculus

This is an example of the problem type I am asking about

Let $f\left(x\right) = \int_1^{2x-x^2} e^{1-t}\, \mathrm{d}t$ Find $f^{\prime}\left(x\right)$

$$\int_1^{2x-x^2} e^{1-t}\, \mathrm{d}t$$ results in $$-e^{1-t}\vert_1^{2x-x^2} = 1-e^{2x-x^2}$$

Then if you differentiate, $$f^{\prime}\left(x\right) = \left(2x-x^2\right)e^{1-2x-x^2}$$

Just thinking there is a better way than just doing the problem directly. Just feel like there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $f(x)=\int_a^xg(t)dt$, then $f'(x)=g(x)$. You will have to apple the chain rule as well, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

See Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: And chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

[The Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part) (the first part here) combined with the chain rule will be very helpful to you.